# php instantiation in separate class

Tags: php, class, instantiation

I have two php files. I would like to instantiate the a class from the first file in a class in the second file. Essentially make several classes and the use another file to access their methods. I'm new-ish to php and I'm having some trouble. the files I'm using would more than likely be in the same directory but if they aren't are there any issues there. I was hoping someone could help me out.

Thanks!

sample code looks like this:

File path = somePath/someDirectory/aFolder/FooClass.php

```
<?php
    class FooClass {
        public function __construct () {}
        public $Foo = "oof";
        public function getFoo () {
            return $this->Foo;
        }
        public function setFoo ($Foo) {
            $this->Foo = $Foo;
        }
    }
?>
```

file path = anotherPath/anotherDirectory/anotherFolder/BarClass.php

```
<?php
    require($lib . '/Library/WebServer/someDirectory/src/aFolder/FooClass.php');
    class BarClass {
        public function __construct () {}
        $f = new FooClass();
        public $Bar = "rab";
        public function getBar () {
            return $this->Bar;
        }
        public function setBar ($Bar) {
            $this->Bar = $Bar;
        }
    }
    $b = new BarClass();
    echo $b->f->getFoo() . "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: What does `I'm having some trouble` mean exactly?

Comment: I'm not having trouble understanding the proper way to instantiate classes and I am not able to access the methods and instance variables the way I expect.  I'm coming from java.

Comment: You should enable error display as your code will generate various errors. Put this at the top of the main script: `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems I can see, is that you are using an expression to define your `$f` property. You cannot do that in php. According to the manual:

> They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or
>   private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration
>   may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a
>   constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile
>   time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be
>   evaluated.

You would need something like:

```
class BarClass {

    public $f;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->f = new FooClass();  
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code `$f` has no [access visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) set, so it's set to `private` by default.

To get access to it outside of `class BarClass`, you need to declare it outside of `__construct` and set it to be `public`.

```
class BarClass {
  public $f;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->f = new FooClass();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but the OP's constructor is actually empty. Your code does solve the / one problem however :-)

Comment: @jeroen oops! Edited the answer to correct the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

> but if the files aren't in the same directories are there any issues

No.

Because you are using absolute paths for `require`:

```
require($lib.'/Library/WebServer/someDirectory/src/aFolder/FooClass.php');
```

Since you are just starting out with PHP, I would encourage you to read about [autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) and take a look at using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) to include one to your codebase.

Comment: Super awesome.  I appreciate the response. I'll check out the links right now.  Thanks for the suggestion!